# what is the difference between didselectrowindexpath and willselectrowindexpath in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Give an explanation about difference between `UITableView` delegate methods:

`didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

`willSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: willSelectRowAtIndexPath is called before the row is selected and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath after the row get selected.

Comment: Can you explain with sample code

Comment: @Prim.Muthu: just writ both method in `.m` file and put break points on them you will understand..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the code written in

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

method is run after selected the row and the code is written in

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

run just before the row selected.

they are same as

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated and - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

let me know if you have any confusion now.

Answer (score 7):

`willSelectRowAtIndexPath` message is sent to the `UITableView` Delegate after the user lifts their finger from a touch of a particular row and before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

`willSelectRowAtIndexPath` allows you to either confirm that the particular row can be selected, by returning the `indexPath`, or select a different row by providing an alternate `indexPath`.

Good luck

T